# Using GPIOPins.cs from RaspberryPiDotNet library

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi

From [this site](https://github.com/cypherkey/raspberrypi.net), you can download a .NET library for Raspberry Pi.

GPIOPins.cs contains the code below. Under the namespace `RaspberryPiDotNet`, there are two public enum objects, `GPIOPins` and `GPIOPinMask`. There are separate variables for GPIO (ex. `V2_GPIO_04`) and pin (ex. `V2_Pin_P1_18`).

What is the difference between `GPIOPins` and `GPIOPinMask`? When do you use the GPIO variables? The pin variables? It also seems that not all of the pins of B+ are included here. B+ has 40 pins, the code only provides up until 26 pins which is for B. In the case that I need to use that pin for GPIO, can I use the GPIO variable instead?

```
namespace RaspberryPiDotNet
{
    /// <remarks>
    /// Refer to http://elinux.org/Rpi_Low-level_peripherals for diagram.
    /// P1-01 = bottom left, P1-02 = top left
    /// pi connector P1 pin    = GPIOnum
    ///                  P1-03 = GPIO0
    ///                  P1-05 = GPIO1
    ///                  P1-07 = GPIO4
    ///                  P1-08 = GPIO14 - alt function (UART0_TXD) on boot-up
    ///                  P1-10 = GPIO15 - alt function (UART0_TXD) on boot-up
    ///                  P1-11 = GPIO17
    ///                  P1-12 = GPIO18
    ///                  P1-13 = GPIO21
    ///                  P1-15 = GPIO22
    ///                  P1-16 = GPIO23
    ///                  P1-18 = GPIO24
    ///                  P1-19 = GPIO10
    ///                  P1-21 = GPIO9
    ///                  P1-22 = GPIO25
    ///                  P1-23 = GPIO11
    ///                  P1-24 = GPIO8
    ///                  P1-26 = GPIO7
    ///                  
    ///                  P5-03 = GPI28
    ///                  P5-04 = GPI29
    ///                  P5-05 = GPI30
    ///                  P5-06 = GPI31
    /// 
    /// So to turn on Pin7 on the GPIO connector, pass in enumGPIOPIN.gpio4 as the pin parameter
    /// </remarks>
    public enum GPIOPins : uint
    {

        GPIO_NONE = uint.MaxValue,

        //Revision 1

        GPIO_00 = 0,
        GPIO_01 = 1,
        GPIO_04 = 4,
        GPIO_07 = 7,
        GPIO_08 = 8,
        GPIO_09 = 9,
        GPIO_10 = 10,
        GPIO_11 = 11,
        GPIO_14 = 14,
        GPIO_15 = 15,
        GPIO_17 = 17,
        GPIO_18 = 18,
        GPIO_21 = 21,
        GPIO_22 = 22,
        GPIO_23 = 23,
        GPIO_24 = 24,
        GPIO_25 = 25,

        Pin_P1_03 = 0,
        Pin_P1_05 = 1,
        Pin_P1_07 = 4,
        Pin_P1_08 = 14,
        Pin_P1_10 = 15,
        Pin_P1_11 = 17,
        Pin_P1_12 = 18,
        Pin_P1_13 = 21,
        Pin_P1_15 = 22,
        Pin_P1_16 = 23,
        Pin_P1_18 = 24,
        Pin_P1_19 = 10,
        Pin_P1_21 = 9,
        Pin_P1_22 = 25,
        Pin_P1_23 = 11,
        Pin_P1_24 = 8,
        Pin_P1_26 = 7,
        LED = 16,

        //Revision 2

        V2_GPIO_00 = 0,
        V2_GPIO_02 = 2,
        V2_GPIO_03 = 3,
        V2_GPIO_01 = 1,
        V2_GPIO_04 = 4,
        V2_GPIO_07 = 7,
        V2_GPIO_08 = 8,
        V2_GPIO_09 = 9,
        V2_GPIO_10 = 10,
        V2_GPIO_11 = 11,
        V2_GPIO_14 = 14,
        V2_GPIO_15 = 15,
        V2_GPIO_17 = 17,
        V2_GPIO_18 = 18,
        V2_GPIO_21 = 21,
        V2_GPIO_22 = 22,
        V2_GPIO_23 = 23,
        V2_GPIO_24 = 24,
        V2_GPIO_25 = 25,
        V2_GPIO_27 = 27,

        //Revision 2, new plug P5
        V2_GPIO_28 = 28,
        V2_GPIO_29 = 29,
        V2_GPIO_30 = 30,
        V2_GPIO_31 = 31,

        V2_Pin_P1_03 = 2,
        V2_Pin_P1_05 = 3,
        V2_Pin_P1_07 = 4,
        V2_Pin_P1_08 = 14,
        V2_Pin_P1_10 = 15,
        V2_Pin_P1_11 = 17,
        V2_Pin_P1_12 = 18,
        V2_Pin_P1_13 = 27,
        V2_Pin_P1_15 = 22,
        V2_Pin_P1_16 = 23,
        V2_Pin_P1_18 = 24,
        V2_Pin_P1_19 = 10,
        V2_Pin_P1_21 = 9,
        V2_Pin_P1_22 = 25,
        V2_Pin_P1_23 = 11,
        V2_Pin_P1_24 = 8,
        V2_Pin_P1_26 = 7,
        V2_LED = 16,

        //Revision 2, new plug P5
        V2_Pin_P5_03 = 28,
        V2_Pin_P5_04 = 29,
        V2_Pin_P5_05 = 30,
        V2_Pin_P5_06 = 31,

    };

    public enum GPIOPinMask : uint
    {

        GPIO_NONE = uint.MaxValue,

        //Revision 1

        GPIO_00 = 0,
        GPIO_01 = 1,
        GPIO_04 = 1 << 4,
        GPIO_07 = 1 << 7,
        GPIO_08 = 1 << 8,
        GPIO_09 = 1 << 9,
        GPIO_10 = 1 << 10,
        GPIO_11 = 1 << 11,
        GPIO_14 = 1 << 14,
        GPIO_15 = 1 << 15,
        GPIO_17 = 1 << 17,
        GPIO_18 = 1 << 18,
        GPIO_21 = 1 << 21,
        GPIO_22 = 1 << 22,
        GPIO_23 = 1 << 23,
        GPIO_24 = 1 << 24,
        GPIO_25 = 1 << 25,

        Pin_P1_03 = 1 << 0,
        Pin_P1_05 = 1 << 1,
        Pin_P1_07 = 1 << 4,
        Pin_P1_08 = 1 << 14,
        Pin_P1_10 = 1 << 15,
        Pin_P1_11 = 1 << 17,
        Pin_P1_12 = 1 << 18,
        Pin_P1_13 = 1 << 21,
        Pin_P1_15 = 1 << 22,
        Pin_P1_16 = 1 << 23,
        Pin_P1_18 = 1 << 24,
        Pin_P1_19 = 1 << 10,
        Pin_P1_21 = 1 << 9,
        Pin_P1_22 = 1 << 25,
        Pin_P1_23 = 1 << 11,
        Pin_P1_24 = 1 << 8,
        Pin_P1_26 = 1 << 7,
        LED = 1 << 16,

        //Revision 2

        V2_GPIO_00 = 1 << 0,
        V2_GPIO_02 = 1 << 2,
        V2_GPIO_03 = 1 << 3,
        V2_GPIO_01 = 1 << 1,
        V2_GPIO_04 = 1 << 4,
        V2_GPIO_07 = 1 << 7,
        V2_GPIO_08 = 1 << 8,
        V2_GPIO_09 = 1 << 9,
        V2_GPIO_10 = 1 << 10,
        V2_GPIO_11 = 1 << 11,
        V2_GPIO_14 = 1 << 14,
        V2_GPIO_15 = 1 << 15,
        V2_GPIO_17 = 1 << 17,
        V2_GPIO_18 = 1 << 18,
        V2_GPIO_21 = 1 << 21,
        V2_GPIO_22 = 1 << 22,
        V2_GPIO_23 = 1 << 23,
        V2_GPIO_24 = 1 << 24,
        V2_GPIO_25 = 1 << 25,
        V2_GPIO_27 = 1 << 27,

        //Revision 2, new plug P5
        V2_GPIO_28 = 1 << 28,
        V2_GPIO_29 = 1 << 29,
        V2_GPIO_30 = 1 << 30,
        V2_GPIO_31 = (uint)1 << 31,

        V2_Pin_P1_03 = 1 << 2,
        V2_Pin_P1_05 = 1 << 3,
        V2_Pin_P1_07 = 1 << 4,
        V2_Pin_P1_08 = 1 << 14,
        V2_Pin_P1_10 = 1 << 15,
        V2_Pin_P1_11 = 1 << 17,
        V2_Pin_P1_12 = 1 << 18,
        V2_Pin_P1_13 = 1 << 27,
        V2_Pin_P1_15 = 1 << 22,
        V2_Pin_P1_16 = 1 << 23,
        V2_Pin_P1_18 = 1 << 24,
        V2_Pin_P1_19 = 1 << 10,
        V2_Pin_P1_21 = 1 << 9,
        V2_Pin_P1_22 = 1 << 25,
        V2_Pin_P1_23 = 1 << 11,
        V2_Pin_P1_24 = 1 << 8,
        V2_Pin_P1_26 = 1 << 7,
        V2_LED = 1 << 16,

        //Revision 2, new plug P5
        V2_Pin_P5_03 = 1 << 28,
        V2_Pin_P5_04 = 1 << 29,
        V2_Pin_P5_05 = 1 << 30,
        V2_Pin_P5_06 = (uint)1 << 31,

    };

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GPIOPIN VS GPIOMask Registers :

GPIO is a technical term in embedded system means General Purpose Input Output. This input output pin is used to control relays, actuator , LED glow or to sense input from sensor or switch.

Every controller multiple input output, which are associated with the contoller PINs. Detailed information can be obtained from the respective datasheet.

**GPIOPins** are reference to this input output pins. You may use this to control /inteface other electronics by changing its value using software. This is possible by changing values in **GPIO** registers

```
value 1 to GPIOpins gets/sets high (+VCC) voltage on pin.
value 0 to GPIOpins gets/sets (0) voltage on pin.
```

sometimes developer requires only specific pins to interface and other pins are kept not connected. To optimize code in such cases, **GPIOPinMask** is used. This utilizes hardware feature, which makes pin ineffective of state change during change in **GPIO** registers.

```
value 1 will mask the PIN for further changes in GPIOPins
value 0 will unmask the PIN, which will affect voltage on pin as above explanation.
```

**EDIT :**

Weather to use GPIO_XX or PIN_XX_XX for GPIOPins enum?

You may use any, that is for developer ease. if you are taking physical position as reference than use **PIN_XX_XX**, if you are using functional reference(see pin layout in schematic) then you should use **GPIO_XX**. Its on developer choice, what reference he takes while writing code.

Comment: I'm still trying to absorb the difference between GPIOPins and GPIOPinMask. On the other note, when do you use the GPIO and pin variable? Let's say in B+, GPIO 10 is at PIN 19. From the code snippet above, GPIO 10 is `GPIO_10` and PIN 19 is `Pin_P1_19`. From that, when will you use `GPIO_10`? `Pin_P1_19`?

Comment: @Harshal Doshi Jain,
Is it possible to read input from a switch or a button using RaspberryPiDotNet?